# libssh v0.6. Timeout Connection when server is SSHV1 & using DES

Tags: libssh

I'm trying to connect to an SSHV1 server(DES), so i used the latest v0.6rc1.

But always got the following error message:

```
[2013/09/16 16:33:08.170438, 1] ssh_connect:  libssh 0.6.0 (c) 2003-2010 Aris Ad
amantiadis (aris@0xbadc0de.be) Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYI
NG file for information about your rights, using threading threads_noop
[2013/09/16 16:33:08.186063, 3] getai:  host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx matches an IP addres
s
[2013/09/16 16:33:08.201687, 2] ssh_socket_connect:  Nonblocking connection sock
et: 3912
[2013/09/16 16:33:08.201687, 2] ssh_connect:  Socket connecting, now waiting for
 the callbacks to work
[2013/09/16 16:33:08.201687, 3] ssh_connect:  ssh_connect: Actual timeout : 1000
0
[2013/09/16 16:33:08.201687, 3] ssh_socket_pollcallback:  Received POLLOUT in co
nnecting state
[2013/09/16 16:33:08.201687, 1] socket_callback_connected:  Socket connection ca
llback: 1 (0)
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.217306, 3] callback_receive_banner:  Received banner: SSH-1
.5-OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.217306, 1] ssh_client_connection_callback:  SSH server bann
er: SSH-1.5-OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.217306, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  Analyzing banner: SSH-1.5-O
penSSH_3.8.1p1
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.217306, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  We are talking to an OpenSS
H client version: 3.8 (30800)
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.217306, 3] ssh_socket_unbuffered_write:  Enabling POLLOUT f
or socket
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.639178, 3] ssh_packet_socket_callback1:  Reading a 187 byte
s packet
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.639178, 3] ssh_packet_socket_callback1:  5 bytes padding
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.639178, 3] ssh_packet_socket_callback1:  The packet is vali
d
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.639178, 3] ssh_packet_process:  Dispatching handler for pac
ket type 2
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.639178, 2] ssh_packet_publickey1:  Got a SSH_SMSG_PUBLIC_KE
Y
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.639178, 2] ssh_packet_publickey1:  Server bits: 640; Host b
its: 512; Protocol flags: 00000002; Cipher mask: 0000004c; Auth mask: 0000000c
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.639178, 2] ssh_packet_publickey1:  Sending SSH_CMSG_SESSION
_KEY
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.732928, 2] ssh_packet_publickey1:  633 bits, 80 bytes encry
pted session
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.732928, 3] packet_send1:  Sending a 100 bytes long packet
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.732928, 3] packet_send1:  100 bytes after comp + 4 padding
bytes = 100 bytes packet
[2013/09/16 16:33:09.732928, 3] ssh_socket_unbuffered_write:  Enabling POLLOUT f
or socket
[2013/09/16 16:33:12.264161, 1] ssh_socket_exception_callback:  Socket exception
 callback: 1 (0)
[2013/09/16 16:33:12.264161, 1] ssh_socket_exception_callback:  Socket error: No
 error
[2013/09/16 16:33:12.264161, 1] ssh_connect:  Timeout connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
[2013/09/16 16:33:12.264161, 3] ssh_connect:  ssh_connect: Actual state : 9
Connection failed : Timeout connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Any one know what happened or is there another solution to connect to sshv1 with DES?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the server log for errors?

If you can't get it working I suggest to ask on the libssh mailing list or open a bug in their bug tracker.